# Store Data in custom index: GWLP_USERDATA_EX?

Tags: c, winapi

How could I go about storing data in a **custom index** using `SetWindowLongPtr(_In_ HWND hWnd, _In_ int nIndex, _In_ LONG_PTR dwNewLong)`?

For example;

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA_CUSTOM, (LONG_PTR)dispatcher);
```

From the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); `nIndex` parameter should be:

> The zero-based offset to the value to be set. Valid values are in the range zero through the number of bytes of extra window memory, minus the size of an integer.

I don't quite understand what this means? How would I determine the number of extra window memory bytes available? Essentially, I'm already using `GWLP_USERDATA` to store a pointer, so I've run out of room. If I could store information in another index it would be very useful.

Comment: You declare how many extra bytes to allocate when you register the window class. The docs for that process explain.

Comment: *"I'm already using GWLP_USERDATA to store a pointer, so I've run out of room"* - That means you haven't registered this window's class (or you'd simply request more room). In that case, using `GWLP_USERFATA` is a bug already. It isn't yours to use.

Comment: I mean, if you are storing a pointer, then you have an essentially unlimited amount of memory at your disposal. Just make the pointer point to a structure that contains all the data you want. Do heed IInspectable's warning, though: `GWLP_USERDATA` is for the person who registered the window class by calling RegisterClassEx, not the person who created the window by calling CreateWindowEx. SetProp is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You decide the number of extra window bytes available when you register your window class through the `cbWndExtra` member of the `WNDCLASS` structure.

For example, if I say

```
wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof (LONG) + sizeof (void *);
```

then I can stuff a `LONG` and a `void *` into my window with

```
SetWindowLongW(hwnd, 0, myLONGValue);
SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, sizeof (LONG), (LONG_PTR) myPointerValue);
```

(To be safe, I would always store values in multiples of pointer-sized integers and use `SetWindowLongPtrW()` exclusively.)

The various `DWLP_xxx` constants you use in a dialog box also work this way.

Note that this implies that you registered the window class yourself; that is, you are the one who called `RegisterClass()` or `RegisterClassEx()`. If you didn't, then you simply do not have permission to access the memory beyond index 0 (unless the author of the window class let you, as is the case with dialog boxes and `DWLP_xxx`). If you have an existing window handle and need to stuff some data related to that window somewhere, you're on your own. (If you are subclassing a window, the Common Controls 6 subclassing routines provide a way for you to store one pointer-sized integer along with your subclass, which helps.)

Substitute "pointer" for "pointer-sized integer" where necessary.

Comment: "you're on your own" - not quite, `SetProp` is a valid alternative.

Comment: The hwnd I am working with is going to be a standard WinAPI button. Would you suggest I use an alternative or stick with `SetWindowLongPtr()`?